# usemin output script in build only

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have my file `index-dev.html` which has this:

```
<!-- build:js https://somelink.com/jquery.min.js -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When I run grunt usemin, it doesn't output

`<script src="https://somelink.com/jquery.min.js"></script>`

in `index.html`. Why is that? This works in usemin 2.0.x but not > 2.1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is possible by doing this:

```
<!-- build:js https://somelink.com/jquery.min.js -->
<!-- <script src="https://somelink.com/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```